# Updated to 20.04 Epson L6170 Networked Printer Not Working

Tags: networking, 20.04, printing, epson

I updated to 20.04 a week back, and I can no longer print to our network printer. The printer shows up in settings, but any time I try to print something, it fails. I have tried printing from Chrome, Document Viewer, and Libre Office. In Chrome, the printer does not even appear. In the latter two, the name shows up, but printing fails.

I have removed the printer and added it again. I have uninstalled ippusbxd and tried re-adding the printer. I have installed the Epson Linux drivers. Every time, the printer is detected, but something fails in the process of adding it and I still cannot print.

It was working perfectly in 18.04 for a year. There is a lot of information on fixing HP printers in 20.04 lying around, but none for Epson. The only thing I have not tried that I saw suggested is installing 20.04 from scratch because that seems rather extreme for a printing problem. Thank you for any help you can offer.

Edit: typing "driverless" in terminal gives me "ipp://EPSON%L6170%20Series._ipp._tcp.local/ "

Comment: ippusbxd is for USB connected printers only. Give what you get for `driverless`.

Comment: driverless gives me: ipp://EPSON%L6170%20Series._ipp._tcp.local/

Answer (score 1):

Same issue. My solution is to run CUPS from a web browser (http://localhost:631/printers/), find the printer there, *rename it*, then save. Now, open Printers app, go to properties, change device URI to App Socket/HP JetDirect. Put the printer's IP address in. I then set a reserved address in the router so things don't change.

You'll show extra printers when you print, ignore any you didn't rename and change to JetDirect. And don't delete them, it'll break what you've done.

First certified downgrade in service I've ever experienced in Ubuntu. Hope it's a hiccup.

Answer (score 0):

ipp://EPSON%L6170%20Series._ipp._tcp.local/ is a URI. See the answer [in this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286761/cannot-print-to-canon-ip110).

Comment: That looks like my solution. Thanks! I'll try it out when I get to work on Monday.

Comment: This is not my solution. I follow the instructions in that answer, and type "lpadmin -p ip500 -v ipp://EPSON%20L6170%20Series._ipp._tcp.local -E -m everywhere" and it tells me  "lpadmin: Unable to connect to "EPSON3DD86D.local:631": Operation now in progress".