# Cannot print to canon ip110

Tags: printing, canon

I use this printer for sometime but I rarelly need to print. Now with Ubuntu 20.04 it does not print at all. It installs the driver automatically, but when I try to print anything it does not print and in the definitions, printers, appears the message: stopped please restart when the problem is solved. I installed a windows 10 in virtualbox to check, and it prints perfectly. I tried to use the usb connect and the WIFI connection. In both ways it does not work.
It worked in version 18.10... Any ideias to solve this? Thank you.[image]

Comment: Have a WiFi connection and give what you get for `driverless`.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: What do I mean? Use the WIFI connection and type `driverless` in a terminal. Send the output here.

Comment: I did not know what driverless was. It outputs this: ipp://Canon%20iP110%20series._ipp._tcp.local/

Comment: I just decided to print a test page from the ubuntu printer configuration and today it worked but it took almost 3 minutes to print it. It makes long pauses while printing. Then i decied to print a page from a PDF. It immediatly appears one job in the printer but it already passed 4 minutes and still did not start printing. Igo to the active jobs of the printer and appear the job as paused! I click play and nothing happens. After 5 minutes the print auto turn off ecause it has nothing to do: so Ubuntu did not even sent any command to the printer.

Comment: Can you please run the command `nslookup -query=soa local` ? It should print 3-4 lines, with the last line containing NXDOMAIN. If you get no NXDOMAIN, your DNS server may be preventing mDNS .local name resolution. Let me know.

Comment: It outputs: Server:  127.0.0.53
Address: 127.0.0.53#53
** server can't find local: NXDOMAIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute this command:

```
lpadmin -p ip500 -v ipp://Canon%20iP110%20series._ipp._tcp.local -E -m everywhere
```

Can you print if you issue the command `lp -d ip500 /etc/nsswitch`?

Comment: The lp command gives an error:lp: Error - unable to access "/etc/nsswitch" - File or folder does not exist. The lpadmin does not give any error neither a message. Nothing happens.

Comment: Sorry, I did not notest that the lpadmin installs a new printer called ip500. And I tried to print to this one and it worked perfectly even gives the status of the ink.

Comment: /etc/nsswitch is a common typo of mine! It should be /etc/nsswitch.conf.  Sorry about that. `lpadmin` only gives an output when there is an error. Getting no output shows it completed successfully.